# NGINX: rewrite specific (variable) path only

Tags: nginx, url, rewrite

I want to rewrite a url containing a specific variable path, for one specific user ip only.

```
http://domain.com/variable
```

Should become:

```
http://domain.com/variable/system
```

However, if there is another path following the /variable path it should remain unchanged. So the following url should stay the same:

```
http:/domain.com/variable/something-else
```

I have tried the following code

```
 if ($http_x_forwarded_for = xxx.xxx.x.xx) {         
           rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/system redirect;
 }
```

However, when running this code it seems to get an a loop, resulting in

```
http://domain.com/variable/system/system/system/system ....
```

I understand what goes wrong, but I do not know how I can easily / correctly fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(.*)` captures the `/` character too. You need to exclude it to prevent a loop.

Try:

```
rewrite ^(/[^/]+)$ $1/system redirect;
```

See [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expressions.